# Send Email to multiple users in an advanced Java loop

Tags: java, spring, object

I have following code:

```
for (User user : users) {
    MailService mserv = new MailService();
    mserv.sendPasswordResetMail(user, null);
}
```

I am using an advanced for loop, so Is it viable to create multiple `MailService` objects? Is it possible that I only create one `MailService` object and can send email to multiple users, code:

```
MailService mserv = new MailService();    
for (User user : users) {
    mserv.sendPasswordResetMail(user, null);
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: By advanced you mean enhanced?

Comment: *What should I do?* -- You should [edit] your post to ask a more concrete question.  Are you trying to ask something about enhanced for loops, or about re-using a `MailService` object?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Also, why not just try it yourself and find out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to iterate only the list of users & send mails. No need to create service objects in loop. Why don't you use Spring's DI for Service layer?